# External VGA monitor port not working on HP Elitebook 2540p running RHEL 6.5

Tags: linux, rhel, x11, video, laptop

I'm running RHEL 6.5 on an HP EliteBook 2540p. When I connect the external VGA port to a projector or external monitor and press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to the external port, nothing happens.

Under *System* -> *Preferences* -> *Display* I only see one monitor. I have looked for Intel VGA drivers for Linux but Intel only offers them for Windows. I've also checked the BIOS and confirmed the port is enabled. What do I need to do to enable the external VGA port in RHEL?

```
My `xorg.conf` is below.

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Videocard0"
    Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

My xrandr output is as follows:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 800, current 1280 x 800, maximum 1280 x 800 default connected 1280x800+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1280x800 0.0
```

Comment: What does `xrandr` show? If you're only seeing one display under System -> Preferences -> Display" then your system is unable to access your VGA port to make use of it.

Comment: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 800, current 1280 x 800, maximum 1280 x 800
default connected 1280x800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x800        0.0*`